# WPF menu and multitouch

Tags: wpf

I have a menu that is implemented in a way that when a menu item is pressed, a popup containing it's sub-items is open.

When running with touch screen, occasionally user touches 2 menu items at the same time with his fingers - and this leads to one of the menuitems have a touch capture which is not released until another window gets focus, making the app seem stuck.

How can I prevent such a case?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause for the problem: the popup used to display submenu items had StaysOpen set to false.

This causes the Popup to capture input so it can know when to close itself once a click was made outside its boundaries.
Setting its StaysOpen property to True fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a queue that contains delegates:

When triggering a command, add the delegate to the queue.
Then grab the first delegate of the queue and flush it afterwards.
Now you only have 1 "command".

Comment: thanks, but this isn't the issue. the issue is that both menu items get a touch capture, but only one of them releases it as only one of the menu items clicks is processed. I need to prevent the menu from allowing 2 sub menu items receive a touch capture at the same time...